# Django Wagtail wagtailcore_tags image TemplateSyntaxError

Tags: python, django, image, syntax-error, wagtail

I am following this [Tutorial](http://wagtail.readthedocs.io/en/v1.13.1/getting_started/tutorial.html) from Wagtail in Images Section to build my blog, 
I am having this weird TemplateSyntax Error which shouldn't be there.

This is my HTML code. I use image from wagtailcore_tags.

```html
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Blog</h1>

    <div class="card-columns">
      {% for post in blogpages %}
        {% with post=post.specific %}
          <a href="{% pageurl post %}">
            <div class="card">

            {% with post.main_image as main_image %}
            {% if main_image %}{% image main_image fill-160x100 %}{% endif %}
            {% endwith %}

              <h5> {{ post.title }} </h3>
              <p> {{ post.date }}</p>
            </div>
          </a>
        {% endwith %}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is my models.py

```html
class BlogPage(Page):
    body = RichTextField()
    date = models.DateField("Post date")

    def main_image(self):
        gallery_item = self.gallery_images.first()
        if gallery_item:
            return gallery_item.image
        else:
            return None

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('date'),
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
        InlinePanel('gallery_images',label= "Gallery images"),
    ]

class BlogPageGalleryImage(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(BlogPage, related_name='gallery_images')
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+'
    )
    caption = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250)

    panels = [
        ImageChooserPanel('image'),
        FieldPanel('caption'),
    ]
```

And, this is the error I am getting:

```
Invalid block tag on line 35: 'image', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

Comment: Did you include `{% load wagtailcore_tags %}` at the top of the template?

Comment: @PeterCollingridge Yes I did

Comment: Did you include `{% load wagtailcore_tags wagtailimages_tags %}` (I should have said that first time)?

Comment: @PeterCollingridge nevermind.... I fixed it by adding {% wagtailimages_tags %} Thanks it helped me looking at the tags from the example